# How do I make the User to input the image in this code using Flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, dart, uri

I have this code to extract color values from an image by Flutter, but in this code use the Uri image.
I need the User he input image instead of the link.

I well use `image_picker`, but I don't know how I can Connection between codes:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  final url ='https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/open_graph/github-octocat.png';    
  final resp = await get(Uri.parse(url)); //Download the image data from the url
  final img = resp.bodyBytes;
  final decodedImg = decodeImage(img); //Decode the received image data
  if (decodedImg == null) {
    throw 'Invalid image';
  }
  final bytesList = decodedImg.data;
  final colorList = bytesList
      .map<Color>((e) => Color(e))
      .toList(); //Map the decoded data to colors
  //Change format to a 2d list of colors so that they can be accessed as colorGrid[x][y]
  final List<List<Color>> colorGrid = [];
  for (int x = 0; x < decodedImg.width; x++) {
    colorGrid.add([]);
    for (int y = 0; y < decodedImg.height; y++) {
      colorGrid[x].add(colorList[x + y * decodedImg.width]);
    }
  }
  print(colorGrid);
}
/// Stores RGBA values
class Color {
  final int alpha, blue, green, red;
  Color(int abgr)
      : alpha = abgr >> 24 & 0xFF,
        blue = abgr >> 16 & 0xFF,
        green = abgr >> 8 & 0xFF,
        red = abgr & 0xFF;
  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'R: $red, G: $green, B: $blue, A: $alpha';
  }
}
```

Comment: does [this](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) cover your needs?

Comment: Yes i used image_picker , but i dont know how i can Connection between codes (image_picker $ this code )

Answer (score 0):

I think image_picker will be best for you where you can take a pic from the camera or gallery

use image_picker
https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

Comment: Yes i used image_picker , but i dont know how i can Connection between codes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).